# Check directories of a removed hard drive

Tags: storage

Is there any way to check **directories list** on a hard drive which was removed from PC like from some Windows cache or temp files?

I wanna know what folders were on that removed hard drive for security reasons because my hard drive was stolen.

Comment: No, you can not check it, it's not stored anywhere.

Comment: If you have backups the directories will be listed there.

Comment: what kind of backup? @TwistyImpersonator

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator: having a backup OP wouldn't have asked for the folders, but could check even the files.

Comment: @MátéJuhász It seems that we should not be assuming what the OP does or does not know. I submit as evidence the fact he asked for a list of folders on a hard drive he doesn't have in his possession.

Comment: @arfb9899 The [backup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_backup), i.e. copy, you should make of any data you do not want to forfeit should the original data be lost or destroyed. It is an exact copy of your data and as such would serve to replace what was on the stolen hard drive.

Comment: If i had a backup I would have not posted here as @MátéJuhász said,the problems is the drive is stolen from my p.c,that is.